# How can I debug HTML elements and javascript in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, svg-animate

I have been working on a project which uses SVG animation.
I works perfectly on PC browsers but it doesn't work in iOS safari and chrome.
And it partially works in android stock browser.
Please help me how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile Chrome browser has a [remote debugging interface](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging).

If i remember correctly, mobile Safari has a debugging console. It's not quite as comprehensive as the remote debugging, but it's okay for rough debugging. If you are on OSX, then xcode might have a more comprehensible debugging tool for mobile websites.